# Writing a buffer into file (stored 1585 byte instead 1580)

Tags: c++, file, char, save, buffer

I will write data from my buffer, which defined as

```
char outBuff[16000];
```

into file. I have loaded data from another file 1580 bytes. After this I stored this data in new file with function WriteAllBytes. In variable `count` was value = 1580, but size of file on disk was 1585 bytes. From there this difference ?

```
static bool WriteAllBytes( char * filename, const char * pWriteBuff, int size)
{
  FILE * pFile = fopen(filename, "w");

  ofstream fout("test.txt");

  if (!pFile)
    return false;

  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (fwrite(pWriteBuff, 1, 1, pFile) != NULL)
    {
      pWriteBuff++;
      count ++;
    }

    fout << *pWriteBuff;
  }

  if (count != size)
    return false;

  fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: Show how you call `WriteAllBytes`. Not directly related to your question: why don't you just call once `fwrite(pWriteBuff, 1, size, pFile)` instead of writing `size` times one singel byte ? BTW look at your code, there is a `}` missing somewhere around  `count ++`.

Comment: Note: Files are already buffered by the OS. If you use `std::ofstream` they are also buffered by the object.

Comment: Update your question instead of commenting.

Comment: @ Michael Walz, 
WriteAllBytes("test3.txt",outBuff, size);
I programmed per single byte for tests

Comment: @Sauber don't answer my comments but _update_ your question.

Comment: Note: `fwrite()` does not return a pointer. so comparing the resuly against `NULL` isnot logical.

Comment: which file? `filename` or `test.txt`

Comment: Please show the part of your program where you call `WriteAllBytes("test3.txt",outBuff, size);` by edikting your question. What's the value of `size` at that moment ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE * pFile = fopen(filename, "w");
```

Should be

```
FILE * pFile = fopen(filename, "wb");
```

You are opening the file in text mode, when you should open in binary mode. On Windows, it will have the consequence to write an additional `\r`(0xD) before every `\n`(0xA).